# Trying to understand how to use and develop using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

On the [Getting started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) page for bootstrap it says if I want to develop using bootstrap source I need bower (which needs node.js and npm)> So on Windows I installed node.js & npm then did `npm install -g bower` which apparently installed bower in my user profile `AppData\Roaming\node_modules\bower` (due to the -g option).

The I ran `bower install bootstrap` and went looking for it in the user profile only to find out that it got installed in the folder `bower_components` in my current folder (or `node_modules\bower` in the current directory if I use the `npm install` command without the `-g` options).

Before I embark in using bootstrap for my development activities I would like to understand more how I am supposed to use it.

I have a project maven spring based web project opened in eclipse (let's call it msb for maven spring based and assume the location is `~/workspace/bs-sample/msb` for the path where the project resides) and I am wondering) and I need to understand:

1. What do I need to install on my desktop to develop with bootstrap beyond the bower and node.js and npm I have already installed and what commands do I need to use?
2. How do I add bootstrap to my msb web project in eclipse?  What folder and what tools need to be installed?
3. What customization do I need to perform to start using bootstrap in my web project.  I actually am trying to use [bootstrap-treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) in my web project.
4. When changing to the bootstrap folder and running `npm install` in what folder will the npm command put the dependencies?  I ask this because I cannot run this command as npm installs its stuff using the git command/ssh and I cannot use ssh because I am behind an HTTP authenticated proxy.  I have to add the dependencies manually.

Any clarification would be much appreciated here and in the getting started page for bootstrap for people unfamiliar with this combination of tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can get started with Bootstrap in one of their three mentioned ways:

- Adding it to your project
- Building from source
- Using the SASS port

If all you want to do is add it to your project, you can use the first option.

For this, you just download the files and add them to your web pages like any other CSS or JS.

The minimized version is best for production, while the non-minimized version is best for debugging issues.

How you include them into your project depends on which framework you are using for you web project (i.e. template engines, tiles, pure JSPs, etc).

You can start with a basic template for a given page and add components (including your treeview) as you see fit.

Template below from Bootstrap's site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```